# What's the best way to do request multiple data from Firebase in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I was wondering what would be the best way to get multiple data from Firebase in an async function to wait for some data from the first request. I'm using this code right now but it's not reliable and it breaks sometimes saying that it can't fetch the data for the second call as it's `undefined`.

```
function useOccasion() {
  const [occasionData, setOccasionData] = useState(null)
  const [friend, setFriend] = useState(null)
  let { occasion } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore.collection('occasions').doc(occasion)
      .onSnapshot(async eventData => {
        setOccasionData({id: eventData.id, ...eventData.data()})

        let friendData = await firestore.collection("friends").doc(eventData.data().friend).get();
        setFriend({id: friendData.id, ...friendData.data()});
      })
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [occasion])

  return [occasionData, friend]
}
```

If there's a more robust way to achieve this that would be amazing.

Comment: "sometimes saying that it can't fetch the data for the second call as it's undefined." -> can you give more details? What is undefined? `eventData.data().friend`?

Comment: `eventData.data().friend` is sometimes undefined in the second call as this data comes from the first request. This bug happens a lot when I'm actually coding. When I save, it triggers a hot reload and this is when the error happens most of the time.

Comment: "is sometimes undefined in the second call as this data comes from the first request. " -> is it undefined, because for some `occasion` documents there is no `friend` data, or because there are some "genuine" errors when fetching the `friends`doc?

Comment: It is an error as if I refresh it comes back to normal.

Comment: Are you sure that ALL `occasion` documents have a `friend` field?

Comment: 100% sure. If I refresh the page I can see the list of all occasions with all associated friends data. So it works but I was more generally intrigued to see if people had another method ass this bug only happen locally.

Comment: It seems that you call the `useOccasion()` function only when needed, so why do you need to use a listener (`onSnapshot`) instead of a simple `get()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215183/discussion-between-charles-de-dreuille-and-renaud-tarnec).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest breaking your data fetches into two hooks, one for each collection occasion and friends.

I'm not sure how you've set firebase up, but I access it through context.

e.g.

```
const useOccasion = () => {
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)

  const [occasions, setOccasions] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.db.collection('occasions')
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.size) {
        let occasionList = []
        snapshot.forEach(doc =>
          occasionList.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id }),
        )

        setOccasions(occasionList)
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        setOccasions([])
        setLoading(false)
      }
    })

    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])

  return { occasions, loading }
}
```

Finally, in your component where you require the data you can access this hook:

```
const { occasions, loading } = useOccasion()
```

Comment: This is usually what I do in most cases but the problem I have is that I need to take an ID from the first request to fetch the second firebase document. To clarify, my document occasion contains the ID of the related friend and then I want to fetch the document of this friend.